# Stripping auto-generated quotation marks using json.dumps( ) (Python)

Tags: python, json

I'm using the json.dumps() method via passing in an OrderedDict. (See below for syntax). It's doing it correctly, but there is one specific field `"labels":` that consistently surrounds the input with `" "` (quotation marks) and I need it not to.

```
desiredJson = OrderedDict([('type', ""), ('labels', '' ), ('bgColor', ''), ('borderColor', '')])

for (category_type, updatedLabels, bgColors, borderColors) in zip(type_, labels_, bgColor_, borderColor_):
    print category_type+updatedLabels
    desiredJson["type"] = category_type
    desiredJson["labels"] = '["%s", "%s"]' % (category_type, updatedLabels)
    desiredJson["bgColor"] = bgColors
    desiredJson["borderColor"] = borderColors

    json.dumps(desiredJson, sort_keys = False, indent = 4, separators=(',' , ': '))
```

Here's what it looks like: (just a sample block, it outputs a lot)

```
{
"type": "Overall",
"labels": "[\"Overall\", \"Over\"]",
"bgColor": "#ff7f8d",
"borderColor": "darken"
}
```

I need it to follow this format:

```
{
"type": "Overall",
"labels": ["Overall", "Over"], // NOTE DIFFERENCE
"bgColor": "#ff7f8d",
"borderColor": "darken"
}
```

** Inserting List into dic **

```
{
"type": "Overall",
"labels": [
    "Overall",
    "Over"
],
"bgColor": "#ff7f8d",
"borderColor": "darken"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because you created the element as a string:

```
desiredJson["labels"] = '["%s", "%s"]' % (category_type, updatedLabels)
```

If you want it to be an array in the JSON, you shoud set it to a Python list:

```
desiredJson["labels"] = [category_type, updated_labels]
```

Comment: This works for putting it in the proper list notation but it creates another problem of formatting... I think json.dump() handles list by indentation. I've included my output from this method in the original post.

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, JSON allows any form of whitespace between elements.

Comment: You're getting that because you used `indent = 4`. That asks for object and array elements to be indented depending on the nesting.